# blob image url (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, blob

I try to use blob to show image in website but how I can get URL outside onload to return it in function?

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "//fiddle.jshell.net/img/logo.png", true);
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";

xhr.onload = function(e) {
    var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array(this.response);
    var blob = new Blob([arrayBufferView]);
    var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);
    //window.URL.revokeObjectURL(imageUrl);
};

xhr.send();
```

Comment: You need to know [How to return a response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: + you don't need to require an arraybuffer if what you want is a blob, XHR also as a `'blob'` responseType.

Answer (score 0):

if you use `imageUrl=urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);` instead `var imageUrl=urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);` you will put your variable in global scope and be able to access outside the function.

```
function yo(lo) {
window.onload=function(e){
lo("give me shiny gold");
}}


yo(function(work) {
alert(work);
});
```

Comment: then there will be the inevitable "how do I return a value from an asynchronous function" question :p

Comment: Give me that shiny gold I need to put a bounty on my question. Anyone want to bother with Ratchet websocket that loss connection only on Windows 10. =)